# mongodb findOneAndUpdate get only updated fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using `mongodb` to insert and update some documents in some collection. When I update a document, I want to get the modified fields only. I can get the complete new document (including the modified fields) by using the `returnOriginal` option for updates, but it gives me all the properties.

From the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate):

> returnOriginal | optional | When false, returns the updated document
>   rather than the original. The default is true

My code is:

```
let result = await db.myCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: ObjectId('5a2451399054bf000453c332')}, 
        data,
        {returnOriginal: true}
    );
```

where `data` can be either one field, or multiple fields, for example:

```
let data = {field1: 'newValue1'};
```

or

```
let data = {field1: 'newValue1', field2: 'newValue2'};
```

I would want to get those fields only, but the result of the update is giving me the entire object, including the _id property and all others, even if they weren't modified.

What I'm looking for is an easy way (a mongodb function or property would be ideal) to **get only the modified fields**, if there is such a way, rather than comparing both objects (before and after).

Using [mongodb node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/):

```
"mongodb": "^3.1.6"
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have such a function unfortunately, you would need to do the comparison using a utility library like lodash or write your own custom function to check the before and after documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

Create a key value pair for the keys you are passing with the value equal to 1 to use in projection.

```
var keys = {}
let data = { field1: 'newValue1', field2: 'newValue2' }
function setUsers(data) {
  for (var k in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      keys[k] = 1
    }
  }
  return keys
}
const projection = setUsers(data)
```

and then use projection in the query to limit the fields

```
db.myCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: ObjectId('5a2451399054bf000453c332') }, 
  data,
  { returnOriginal: true, projection }
)
```

Comment: Yes this is my current approach, but was wishing mongodb had a native option or function that did this. Only thing with this solution is that it won't help for nested properties, objects or arrays, but of course it's a solution I've already solved before. Thank you!

Comment: Well chridam is right there is no function available in mongodb right now.